# C# ¿IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, sql-server, login, sha256

Estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión en `C#` y `SQL Server`, con una tabla que acabo de crear. En esta tabla, almaceno las contraseñas de los usuarios con un hash `SHA2_256`.

Al hacer el login, utilizo este código:

```
 var.User = txtUser.Text;
 var.Pswd = txtPass.Text;

 BaseDatos conexion = new BaseDatos();
            using (conexion) {
                //try {
                    SqlCommand userQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Usuario, Pswd, Rol FROM UsuariosSHA WHERE Usuario = @usrn AND Pswd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @pass);", conexion.conexionSistema());
                    userQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrn", var.User);
                    userQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", var.Pswd);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(userQuery);
                    da.Fill(ds, "UsuariosSHA");
                    DataRow DR;
                    DR = ds.Tables["UsuariosSHA"].Rows[0];

                    if ((var.User == DR["Usuario"].ToString()) || (var.Pswd == DR["Pswd"].ToString())) {
                        agPrincipal agendaPW = new agPrincipal(var.User);
                        agendaPW.Show();
                        Dispose();
                    }
             /*} catch (Exception) {
                /////
            }*/
```

Me da error en:

> DR = ds.Tables["UsuariosSHA"].Rows[0];, del tipo `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Supongo que la consulta no me está arrojando resultados.

Por otro lado, si pongo la consulta

```
SELECT Usuario, Pswd, Rol FROM UsuariosSHA 
WHERE Usuario = 'PRUEBA' AND Pswd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'PRUEBA');
```

De manera estática, sólo de prueba, efectivamente puedo iniciar sesión.

También si hago la declaración manual en SSMS, el query funciona. Me regresa el usuario PRUEBA:

```
DECLARE @val2 varchar(30);   
DECLARE @val1 varchar(30);

SET @val1 = 'PRUEBA';
SET @val2 = 'PRUEBA';

SELECT Usuario, Pswd FROM UsuariosSHA 
WHERE Usuario=@val1 AND Pswd=HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',@val2);
```

Mi tabla tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE UsuariosSHA(
    Numemp INT NOT NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Usuario VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Pswd VARBINARY(150) NOT NULL,
    Rol VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

alter table UsuariosSHA ADD CONSTRAINT UK_Password UNIQUE (Numemp);
alter table UsuariosSHA ADD CONSTRAINT UK_UserName UNIQUE (Usuario);
```

En el inicio de sesión, intenté cambiar la consulta a:

```
SELECT Usuario, Pswd, Rol FROM UsuariosSHA 
WHERE Usuario = @usrn AND Pswd = @pass;
```

Y agregar el siguiente método para hacer el hash de la cadena y compararla con el campo Pswd de la tabla:

```
public string SHA256Encrypt(string input)
        {
            var crypt = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
            var hash = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            byte[] crypto = crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            foreach (byte theByte in crypto)
            {
                hash.Append(theByte.ToString("x2"));
            }
            return hash.ToString().ToUpper();
        }
```

Y después de recoger la información del textbox, mandarla a llamar:

```
var.Pswd = SHA256Encrypt(var.Pswd);
```

Sin embargo, obtuve los mismos resultados.

A razón de prueba, ya intenté quitar los ambos parámetros, dejar sólo el de usuario... Pero al tratar la contraseña como variable, es donde el sistema me arroja dicha excepción.

¿Alguien sabe cuál la razón de esta excepción o que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba esto: `String varible = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Usuario"].ToString()` para probar si hay algun valor alli

Comment: Ya lo intenté. Obtuve el mismo error.

Answer (score 1):

La excepción te la está dando porque intentas acceder a la primera `DataRow` de una tabla que no tiene ninguna. ¿Por qué? es cuestión de tu consulta.

Para manejar estos casos escribí el siguiente código:

```
public static bool GetFirstRow(DataTable table, ref DataRow row)
{
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        row = table.Rows[0];
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        row = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Y lo consumirías así:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(userQuery);
da.Fill(ds, "UsuariosSHA");
DataRow DR;
// Ojo aquí abajo
if (GetFirstRow(ds.Tables["UsuariosSHA"], ref DR)
{
    if ((var.User == DR["Usuario"].ToString()) || (var.Pswd == DR["Pswd"].ToString())) {
        ...
    }
}
```

***¿Cómo funciona?***

Cuando utilizas un [parámetro `ref`](https://elmapacheprogramador.blogspot.com/2014/06/ref-vs-out-en-csharp.html) usas una referencia a una variable que ya existe y le asignas un valor desde el método. La razón para que el método devuelva un `bool` es simplemente para que, en caso de que se pueda usar la variable, solo sea cuestión de meterlo adentro de un `if` y así asegurarnos que el código solo se ejecutará si podemos usar ese dato.

---

Por otro lado, yo llenaría directamente una `DataTable` en lugar de un `DataSet` para asegurarme de que la tabla con la que vaya a trabajar por lo menos exista y no dé otra `IndexOutOfRangeException` por no encontrar el nombre de la tabla:

```
try
{
    DataTable dt;
    using (SqlConnection con = ...)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("query", con))
        {
            ... // SqlParameters

            dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd))
            {
                con.Close();
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT

Algo que valdrá la pena revisar es el tipo de dato que se esté manejando. Para asegurarte que se mande como debe haz lo siguiente:

```
SqlCommand userQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Usuario, Pswd, Rol FROM UsuariosSHA WHERE Usuario = @usrn AND Pswd = @pass;", conexion.conexionSistema());
userQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrn", var.User);
SqlParameter passParam = new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@pass",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary,
    Value = SHA256Encrypt(var.Pswd)
};
userQuery.Parameters.Add(passParam);
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, Kroneaux, desconocía el parámetro ref. Sin embargo, lo intenté y mi problema sigue. Como dices, imagino debe ser la consulta. No entiendo porque al copiarla, pegarla en el SMSS y declarar allí la variable pass, funciona. Si en el SqlCommand, dejo la consulta estática, funciona. Debe ser  error al mandar el parámetro pass, pero no entiendo porque falla al tratarlo como variable y no como un valor estático.

Comment: @Nohemi He actualizado mi respuesta, coméntame si funciona :D

Comment: No, Kroneaux, no me ha funcionado. En el parámetro value del parámetro, añadí  Value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SHA256Encrypt(var.Pswd)) por que me daba error al convertir string a byte. Pero aún así, mi consulta me sigue arrojando la misma excepción.

Comment: Valdría la pena poner una marca en esas líneas y depurar. ¿Puedes corroborar que los parámetros tengan los valores correctos?